# Calculating mean difference between combinations of dates

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the pairwise average and median number of days between multiple date variables.

My raw data `df` might look as following:

```
id     invitation    account_date   first_order    second_order    third_order
1    1/1/2016      1/7/2016       1/20/2016      1/22/2016        NA
2    1/1/2016      1/8/2016       1/22/2016      1/23/2016        1/25/2016
3    1/1/2016      1/5/2016       1/20/2016      2/1/2016         NA
4    1/1/2016      1/2/2016       1/18/2016      2/4/2016         2/6/2016
```

Given that my data are already properly formatted as dates, it's pretty easy to manually calculate the average and median difference for the combinations of dates by first calculating the pairwise differences, e.g.:

```
id     inv_to_act act_to_first    act_to_sec    act_to_third
1      6          13              2             NA
2      7          14              1             2
3      4          15              12            NA
4      1          16              17            2
```

And then using base R: `mean(df$act_to_first,na.rm=T)`.

But, I'd like to compute these calculations on several datasets or subsets of the same dataset, so it's not scalable to do each step over and over again. Plus, I'm pretty sure there must be a `melt` or `plyr` solution that I haven't figured out.

Comment: If you have many datasets, you can place them in a `list` and use `lapply`

Comment: @akrun I actually need to run this on subsets of data, thus `plyr` seems like it would be more ideal. Guidance on `lapply` would also be much appreciated :)

Comment: If you need to run with a group by condition, then you can use `dplyr/data.table`

Comment: @akrun Could you possibly help me get started? I know a bit of `dplyr` but keep getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the date differences between each pair of dates by looping through the pairs and using `difftime`:

```
combos <- combn(tail(names(df), -1), 2)
diffs <- apply(combos, 2, function(x) {
  difftime(df[,x[2]], df[,x[1]], units="days")
})
colnames(diffs) <- paste0(combos[1,], "_TO_", combos[2,])
diffs
#      invitation_TO_account_date invitation_TO_first_order invitation_TO_second_order invitation_TO_third_order account_date_TO_first_order
# [1,]                          6                        19                         21                        NA                          13
# [2,]                          7                        21                         22                        24                          14
# [3,]                          4                        19                         31                        NA                          15
# [4,]                          1                        17                         34                        36                          16
#      account_date_TO_second_order account_date_TO_third_order first_order_TO_second_order first_order_TO_third_order second_order_TO_third_order
# [1,]                           15                          NA                           2                         NA                          NA
# [2,]                           15                          17                           1                          3                           2
# [3,]                           27                          NA                          12                         NA                          NA
# [4,]                           33                          35                          17                         19                           2
```

After you do that step, you should be able to easily compute the average of each column:

```
colMeans(diffs, na.rm=TRUE)
#   invitation_TO_account_date    invitation_TO_first_order   invitation_TO_second_order    invitation_TO_third_order  account_date_TO_first_order 
#                          4.5                         19.0                         27.0                         30.0                         14.5 
# account_date_TO_second_order  account_date_TO_third_order  first_order_TO_second_order   first_order_TO_third_order  second_order_TO_third_order 
#                         22.5                         26.0                          8.0                         11.0                          2.0
```

Once you have these functions, you can put them together in a function and apply that function to any input `df`:

```
meanDateRanges <- function(df) {
  combos <- combn(tail(names(df), -1), 2)
  diffs <- apply(combos, 2, function(x) {
    difftime(df[,x[2]], df[,x[1]], units="days")
  })
  colnames(diffs) <- paste0(combos[1,], "_TO_", combos[2,])
  colMeans(diffs, na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

You could run this function on an input data frame with `meanDateRanges(df)` or on a list of them with `lapply(df.list, meanDateRanges)`.

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, invitation = structure(list(sec = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    mday = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(116L, 
    116L, 116L, 116L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), yday = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EST", "EST", 
    "EST", "EST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), account_date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
    min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(7L, 
    8L, 5L, 2L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(116L, 116L, 
    116L, 116L), wday = c(4L, 5L, 2L, 6L), yday = c(6L, 7L, 4L, 
    1L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EST", "EST", "EST", 
    "EST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), first_order = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
    min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(20L, 
    22L, 20L, 18L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(116L, 116L, 
    116L, 116L), wday = c(3L, 5L, 3L, 1L), yday = c(19L, 21L, 
    19L, 17L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EST", "EST", 
    "EST", "EST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), second_order = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
    min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(22L, 
    23L, 1L, 4L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), year = c(116L, 116L, 
    116L, 116L), wday = c(5L, 6L, 1L, 4L), yday = c(21L, 22L, 
    31L, 34L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("EST", "EST", 
    "EST", "EST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", 
"year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), third_order = structure(list(sec = c(NA, 0, NA, 0
), min = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L), hour = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L), mday = c(NA, 
25L, NA, 6L), mon = c(NA, 0L, NA, 1L), year = c(NA, 116L, NA, 
116L), wday = c(NA, 1L, NA, 6L), yday = c(NA, 24L, NA, 36L), 
    isdst = c(-1L, 0L, -1L, 0L), zone = c("", "EST", "", "EST"
    ), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    )), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", 
"wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = c("id", "invitation", "account_date", "first_order", 
"second_order", "third_order"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```